# Identifier Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting an error that tells me that there is an identifier expected?

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    ProductRepository repo = new ProductRepository();
    var product = repo.GetProductID(id);

    string Pid = collection["Pid"];
    string name = collection["PName"];
    string type = collection["PType"];
    string deal = collection.["PDeal"];
    string desc = collection.["PDescription"];
    string price = collection.["PPrice"];
    repo.Save();

    return View("index");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have an extra `.` in these three lines:

```
string deal = collection.["PDeal"];
string desc = collection.["PDescription"];
string price = collection.["PPrice"];
```

Comment: Thanks man lol! never even noticed them. been a long day :(